# Google Sheets: Align Imported Data (via Importrange) Automatically with Manually Entered Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two spreadsheets

[Sheet1: employee_info](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r7cCcQ-s08LzoQf1NlFki5ND7Y4swqiSLOxNPwV5Hes/edit#gid=2106324579) is a spreadsheet with all employee's info. It is dynamic and always updating since it's using an import range to collect info from other sheets.

[Sheet2: employee_info_with_additional_details](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18fLdCSHfesZuaNKvr45tiyWZ1BGhBjaAFjak8H0eUKU/edit#gid=0) is a spreadsheet that is importing info from Sheet1 and contains manual entry such as "Working From Home?".

What I'd like to do is, if a new employee is introduced in Sheet1, then I want it to appear in Sheet2. I created primary keys and foreign keys and used index match in my Sheet2 but I am having issue if someone adds a new employee to Sheet1. How can I have the primary keys in Sheet2 update dynamically without doing so manually? Thanks.

Comment: Since Sheet 1 is importing the data from another sheet, how is the other sheet getting the source data? I am asking because depending on how the data entry is being managed, you could do this using Apps Script and triggers.

Comment: @FernandoLara, Sheet2 is a centralized sheet and getting data via importrange from 4 other different sheets (product_manager_sheet, business_analyst_sheet, accountant_sheet, marketing_specialist_sheet) Sheet1  is pulling info from Sheet2 and so that many stalkholders can enter in additional info and create new columns to enter other info.

Comment: You mentioned that `Sheet1 is pulling info from Sheet2`, but you also mention that `if a new employee is introduced in Sheet1, then I want it to appear in Sheet2`. Are you introducing data manually into Sheet1 besides the import range?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. Sheet2 (employee_info_with_additional_details) is retrieving info from Sheet1 (employee_info). If a new employee is introduced in Sheet1 (employee_info), then I want the new employee to be introduced automatically in Sheet2. I am trying to figure out how to update the Primary Keys automatically in Sheet2.

Comment: Perfect. That being said I think it would be important to understand where the data is coming from. You mentioned that `Sheet1` is using import range to retrieve the data, however whit that reasoning that data is being pulled from somewhere else. How are you manually introducing that data in the source? It is important to understand this to see if there is a way for you to work with Apps Script triggers to accomplish what you need.